# WCF, WIF, Android, and iOS Oh my

Tags: android, ios, wcf, wif

I have a MVC application that I would like to port at least a small part of it to a mobile app (android first).  My first objective was to try to figure out how to authenticate the users.

It seems that forms based authentication uses cookies and that is not usable by mobile apps? Definitive confirmation would be appreciated.

But it seemed that you could do some form of authentication using a WCF service to create a token.  Now I found a lot of sites that discussed how to create and secure the service end point but none really discussed the token generation.

Then quite by accident I stumbled upon WIF and the usersecuritytoken, which seems to what I am looking to accomplish.

So if some could please confirm this is where I need to be looking so I can actually get back to coding rather than reading I would appreciate it.

The way I see this working is:

1. Secure WCF service.
2. Using the System.IdentityModel it generates a token for a valid user and passes it back to the mobile app.
3. Then the app passes the token along anytime a service requiring privilege is called. For example updating the user's profile.

Is that how it is suppose to work? If not could you please point me to an example of how it is suppose to work.

One other question, looking at the WIF site it seems to provide a lot of token types, what is the preferred type for android and iOS?

**UPDATE** As it was pointed out it would be helpful if I provided more context.
The original website is a MVC3 web app.

I am attempting to write an app for some of the backend administration features using mono touch.

WCF seems to be a bad solution for cross platform and a package called ServiceStack is what I am now leaning towards for my web services.  ServiceStack has its own authentication module but it does not interface with the .net membershipprovider which is an issue since the web app was designed with the membership provider.

I have to be overthinking this.  It can't be this complicated to have an android or iphone app securely authenticate to a .net membership provider through some form of web service.

Thank you in advance,
Chris

Comment: It'd be useful is you describe the architecture of the mobile app you are building: is it a browser based app? native?

Comment: I can confirm with you that "It seems that forms based authentication uses cookies" CAN BE DONE on Android AND iOS. You will have to keep track of return cookies and/or response headers and store them securely (Android AccountManager OR iOS keychain). Not sure how it would be done via mono touch but you can def pull off a hybrid app if anything. If you really want security you should look into doing it natively on each platform and follow the best practices. For server side, you can follow Facebook/Google's model for mobile apps.

Comment: Thank you Edison, I shall look into those for starting points.